# Converting colored output into html

Tags: command-line, terminal, colors, diff, output

There are tools providing coloured output:

```
dwdiff -c File1 File2 # word level diff
grep --color=always # we all know this guy
...
```

The question is: **How to convert their colored output of arbitrary program into coloured html file?**

Other output formats might be suitable as well (LaTeX would be great).
I think html is good starting point, as it's easy to convert it to other formats.

(For curious how to keep terminal colour codes, please follow answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10832/9689 
`... | unbuffer command_with_colours arg1 arg2 | ...` - tool [unbuffer](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) is part of [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) )

Comment: If you like dwdiff, you might also like colordiff, a wrapper that colorizes diff's output. I've aliased diff=colordiff for years, never had any problems.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245121/a-library-to-convert-ansi-escapes-terminal-formatting-color-codes-to-html) is probably what you want.

It links to these tools, which do the conversion you're looking for:

- Perl package [HTML::FromANSI](http://search.cpan.org/~nuffin/HTML-FromANSI-2.03/)
- [aha](http://ziz.delphigl.com/tool_aha.php), a C-language program ([github repo](https://github.com/theZiz/aha))

Comment: `aha` is also available in Ubuntu: `sudo apt install aha`. But note that some commands will suppress colors when the output is a pipe. So when sending output to aha, you may need to add options to your commands. For `ls` or `grep` it would be `--color=always`.

Comment: Also available for MacOS: `brew install aha`

Comment:  for introducing me to `aha` ☺. Thanks.

Comment: aha seems buggy, it isn't escaping html entities in the original text before converting it.

Answer (score 31):

Or just a shell script

https://github.com/pixelb/scripts/blob/master/scripts/ansi2html.sh

More details of this script http://pablomarin-garcia.blogspot.com/2011/04/converting-ansi-to-html-how-to-convert.html

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is the only answer I could get to work on Amazon Linux 2

Comment: "just" a shell script... 500 lines long, with a giant script for awk. Just why?!

Comment: @YarekT I'm doubting that you can re-implement it in fewer hundred lines of code. Maybe more than 800 hundred lines of Python code? https://github.com/pycontribs/ansi2html/blob/main/src/ansi2html/converter.py Or 12k lines of C code? https://github.com/theZiz/aha/blob/master/aha.c, or the best you can choose is 400 lines of Perl? https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/NUFFIN/HTML-FromANSI-2.03/lib/HTML/FromANSI.pm

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if 500 lines of Shell code can not make you comfortable, any of those are neither. But if you are happy with a pip install CLI from a nobody, we shouldn't talk. I'm not that guy who arrogantly thinks that these details should be comprehensively solved by a 3rd party library.

Comment: Shell scripts, while useful in many contexts, have their limit. There are better languages that offer a bit more sanity when dealing with complicated problems. Props for solving this in a shell script at the time. I think collectively we have better tooling now (readable + testable + maintainable + nicely portable maybe?). Alas I don't have time, so not trying to take anything away from the answer, or solution. Hopefully that explains the my reaction from my previous comment.

Comment: Let's walk the walk. An HTML render for ANSI Escape Codes needs a parser and a rewriter at minimal implementation. These implementations I posted have the same logic. The only difference is the language's manipulation of string. Everyone is busy with their stuff, and it's easy to answer these "standard" answers. But please really think about it.

Answer (score 12):

[ansi2html](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ansi2html/), on pypi.

One may derive immoderate amounts of enjoyment from piping regular shell output through [lolcat](https://github.com/busyloop/lolcat/) then through ansi2html. Some thing like:

```
… | lolcat -f | ansi2html -ip
```

Comment: +1 for LaTeX output. I'd give you +1 for the `lolcat` idea alone, but I'm too busy laughing.

Comment: fyi, Debian's *colorized-logs* package installs an incompatible `ansi2html` binary executable

Answer (score 8):

You can try `vim` with [AnsiEsc.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) plugin to view ANSI colors through escape codes, then redirect to standard output to `vim -` (make sure you've activated `:syntax on`). Then convert the file to HTML by vim command: `:TOhtml`. The generated HTML file should have coloured output.

---

To convert source code non-interactively into html, try the following command:

```
vim -E -s -c "let g:html_no_progress=1" -c "syntax on" -c "set ft=c" -c "runtime syntax/2html.vim" -cwqa myfile.c
```

<sup>Source: `:help g:html_no_progress` (part of `:help TOhtml`).</sup>

<sup>Note: You can use `-` instead of the `myfile.c`, to convert code from standard input.</sup>

Comment: This didn't work for me. It would help if you would explain the command.

Comment: This command has been explained in Vim manual, check by `:help TOhtml` or `:help g:html_no_progress`.

Comment: The way you wrote that is confusing.
Use AnsiEsc.vim plugin. Activate it with :syntax on, and then you can see the text properly styled in the ANSI formatting? After that, save the file as html using :TOhtml?

Comment: I got it to work, so your answer was the simplest, but understanding your instructions took more work than the solution. :-)

Comment: If you've any suggestions on how to improve the steps, feel free to improve.

Comment: I offered them in my comment. If I understood the instruction correctly. I guess you're suggesting I edit the answer? Which is fine. I can do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use vim. This is part of a script I use to convert diff output to HTML.

```
vim -n \
    -c ':%s%^+  %+++    ' \
    -c ':%s%^-  %---    ' \
    -c ':%s%^   %       ' \
    -c ':set nu' \
    -c ':let html_use_css=1' \
    -c ':so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/2html.vim' \
    -c ':wq' -c ':qa!' $input > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

After this, I run sed to change the CSS and the title to be exactly what I want them to be.

*Edit: I should have mentioned that to get color, you need to have syntax highlighting turned on. I do that in my .vimrc, but if you wanted to add it here it would just be another line like

```
-c ':syntax on' \
```

Comment: Ok. So how would you like to convert output of arbitrary program, let's say : grep ?

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand at first. If you want to convert ANSI color codes, then the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245121/a-library-to-convert-ansi-escapes-terminal-formatting-color-codes-to-html) is probably what you want. If you just need a quick hack, then creating a sed script with a bunch of lines that replace ANSI codes with HTML would work. Something like 's,^[\\[31m,<span style='color:red'>,g s,^[\\[m,</span>,g' would be quick and dirty, but possibly sufficient.

Comment: Could you @user17591 put this link as one more answer? I'd love to select it as answer to my question, and higher your reputation.

Comment: Ok. I added a direct link to the Perl module so that any subsequent user will be able to find it with one less level of indirection, but also a link to the original question/answer for attribution.

Comment: @user17591, nice solution! (+1) I just end-up adding a 2 year old vimshell followup variant of your solution!

Answer (score 2):

*Update:* I've added a `perl` method, using [module HTML::FromANSI from CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~nuffin/HTML-FromANSI-2.03/lib/HTML/FromANSI.pm) .. To install it, just extract it to a directory, and run, as root: `perl -MCPAN -e 'install HTML::FromANSI'` from that directory.  The particular feature to suit your request is a script called `ansi2html`.  Interestingly enough, it shows the same loss-of-color after the overlaid `k` in the filenames,  as does the *elisp-shell* script...  Here is an example usage:

```
ls -l --color=always /bin/*k* | 
 grep --color=always "k\|x\|2010" |
  ansi2html  >/tmp/example.html
firefox /tmp/example.html
```

Here is the html output. as seen in Firefox:

[image]

---

Here is a method using an *emacs* [elisp-shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6259330/313821)... for the example, called *htmlize* ...Emacs does not need to be running.

I originally tested it on a black background, but I noticed that for some reason, a white background doesn't play well with one of the introduced Escape Codes,`\e[K`, which seems to be ERASE_LINE *(Erase the current line of terminal output)*. I've added a line to remove this Escape Code. It now works for a white background.

Here is an example of color highlighted output from `ls` being piped to `grep` for further color highlighting.

```
ls -l --color=always /bin/*k* | 
 grep --color=always "k\|x\|2010" >/tmp/example
htmlize /tmp/example
firefox /tmp/example.html
```

this is the `elsip-shell` script.

```
#!/bin/sh
":"; exec /usr/bin/emacs -Q --script "$0" -- "$@" # -*-emacs-lisp-*-
(require 'ansi-color) (require 'htmlize)
(find-file (setq path-in (cadr argv)))
(ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))
(switch-to-buffer (buffer-name (htmlize-buffer)))
(write-file (concat path-in ".html"))
```

Here is a sample of the html output, in Firefox... If I get time, I'll look further into the overlaying ANSI codes issue. where the red `k`s overlap the green filenames, but that is only there because of a hurriedly chosen test regex for grep... (maybe that is something `\e[K` influences...

[image]

Comment: Sounds nice. It would be great if there would be smaller tool for this task (emacs takes ~100MB).

Answer (score 2):

As of 2021, there also is `ansi2html` which is avaliable in the Debian package "colorized-logs".

Comment: which is incompatible with/breaks the [pypi version I mentioned earlier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/converting-colored-output-into-html/303529#303529)

Comment: I fail to see the point. https://github.com/kilobyte/colorized-logs and https://github.com/pycontribs/ansi2html are completely different projects. You may use one or the other.

Comment: If you've previously been using the pypi ansi2html, then install the Debian package colorized-logs, it will replace the existing ansi2html command with an incompatible one. This was a problem for me, so I make sure that colorized-logs is blocked from my Debian systems

Comment: Strange. Executables installed by pip usually go into `~/.local/bin` and apt installs to `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

There is simple and versatile npm command line tool [ansi-to-html](https://github.com/rburns/ansi-to-html) that can convert easily shell colored output to html.

```
git log --color | ansi-to-html --newline > ansi.html
```

There are options to change the foreground and background color also.

```
    -f, --fg         The background color used for resets (#000)
    -b, --bg         The foreground color used for resets (#FFF)
```

[ansi-to-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi-to-html) npm module.

It can also be used without installing, with npx command.

```
git log --color | npx ansi-to-html --newline > ansi.html
```

Comment: This is a lifesaver. Just note if you don't explicitly add `--color` then piping will prevent coloring (git will assume pipelines need pure plaintext output).

Answer (score 1):

For those who have a command that is written on the assumption that piped output will never have color (e.g. some testing frameworks) you may find it useful to use the script utility to first save the ansi output. This can then be pushed to aha or the other utilities mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a followup of @user17591 solution -- **vim scripting**:

```
#!/usr/bin/vim -ns
:%s%^+  %+++
:%s%^-  %---
:%s%^   %
:set nu
:let html_use_css=1
:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/2html.vim
:wq
:qa!
```

chmod it and

Usage: `htmlvim file` (to produce file.html)