# Colored grep output getting fragmented by watch command

Tags: grep, colors, watch

I'm trying to run `watch`, so that it shows me the output from my grep command, while I am running over files and changing things.

The usual way of doing this works fine, but lacks colors:

```
watch grep 'something' **/*
```

...and since I do want colors, I did this:

```
watch grep 'something' **/* --color=always
```

It's still ugly, because watch doesn't parse the escape codes that make the colors work. So then I found this:

```
watch --color grep 'something' **/* --color=always
```

And well... it doesn't work. The output is fragmented / mixed up in some weird way. It shows me only a single line for some reason, while without `watch --color` the grep outputs about 20.

How can I make `watch` work with colorized output from `grep`?

---

### **Isolated case:**

Using the following:

```
mkdir grep_test; cd grep_test
echo "asdsad\nasdasd\nsaasdasd" > file1 
echo "test\n123\ntest" > file2
```

I create two files, and run the following command:

```
grep test * --color=always
```

Which works as expected, and outputs (with colors and whatnot):

```
file2:test
file2:test
```

But when I use watch:

```
watch --color 'grep test * --color=always'
```

It outputs nothing. Without the `--color` option it shows the right output, though without the ANSI escapes interpreted.
I'm running this on Fedora 25, in tmux session with zsh inside.

Also, `watch -v` output is:

```
watch from procps-ng 3.3.10
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that **watch** does work with color output. But specifically for **grep** you should make some workaround (according to [grep --color adds ANSI code ESC[K - This can change displayed text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45190/grep-color-adds-ansi-code-esck-this-can-change-displayed-text))

```
watch --color "GREP_COLORS=ne grep --color=always .* *"
```

Comment: I tried using this, and the highlighted color is every single characters and subsequent lines after the grep search pattern. I am running on CentOS7 with tcsh interpreter

Comment: It was just an example. I case of matching only 'test' you should use modified pattern:
watch --color "GREP_COLORS=ne grep --color=always test *"